# why does lldb skips this line?

Tags: swift, xcode, llvm, lldb

I am currently trying to learn swift and while I was coding some dummy stuff, I noticed the xcode is skipping some lines and sometimes stops on weird lines . my env: macos sierra,xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)

since xcode is skipping some lines , I thought the problem is from code optimisation , then I switched to terminal to debug, below is the input&output

I compiled using

```
swiftc -g -Onone *.swift
```

then

load it with lldb

```
lldb main
```

set breakpoint on lint 18 as shown below and process run with "r"

```
   17   do {
-> 18       try StaticM.teststatic2()
   19       print (1)
   20   }catch {
   21       
(lldb) thread step-in
Process 963 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x86e1, 0x0000000100001f6a main`static StaticM.teststatic2(self=main.StaticM, $error=Error @ 0x00007fff5fbffac0) throws -> () + 26 at staticExt.swift:13, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step in
    frame #0: 0x0000000100001f6a main`static StaticM.teststatic2(self=main.StaticM, $error=Error @ 0x00007fff5fbffac0) throws -> () + 26 at staticExt.swift:13
   10   public extension StaticM {
   11       @discardableResult
   12       public static func teststatic2() throws  {
-> 13           var asdf=2;
   14           let sdfgsdfg=2;
   15           print(sdfgsdfg);
   16           print (asdf);
(lldb) n
Process 963 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x86e1, 0x0000000100001f72 main`static StaticM.teststatic2(self=main.StaticM, $error=Error @ 0x00007fff5fbffac0) throws -> () + 34 at staticExt.swift:15, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = step over
    frame #0: 0x0000000100001f72 main`static StaticM.teststatic2(self=main.StaticM, $error=Error @ 0x00007fff5fbffac0) throws -> () + 34 at staticExt.swift:15
   12       public static func teststatic2() throws  {
   13           var asdf=2;
   14           let sdfgsdfg=2;
-> 15           print(sdfgsdfg);
   16           print (asdf);
   17           asdf += 1;
   18       }
(lldb) process continue
Process 963 resuming
2
2
1
Process 963 exited with status = 0 (0x00000000) 
(lldb)
```

question is , after I go to next line using "n" in lldb, why lldb skips line 14 of staticExt.swift and jumps straight to line 15 ?

also , sometimes when trying to debug some other program, I click on "step-in" in xcode, it stops on the declaration line of the func instead of first line in the code block, I clicked stepover , it goes back to the caller func line instead of executing the first line of that func.

in all,programe works , but why lldb jumps even with -Onone and -g ? 
could you please let me where can I find more info ?
thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift's basic types (Int's, Strings, etc.) are formally somewhat heavy-weight - for instance in your example:

```
(lldb) expr --raw -- asdf
(Swift.Int) $R0 = {
  _value = 3
}
```

To make performance acceptable even though this is true, the swift compiler "unboxes" these types in common operations and applies other "optimization-like" tricks to make all this go faster.  Since this is such a pervasive feature of swift, it does so even at -Onone, to make performance of unoptimized code acceptable.  And once the optimizer starts getting involved, it sometimes can't help itself and will do more work than maybe it should at -Onone.

In this case, because the first variable is a "let" of an Int, swiftc knows it can just directly insert the value into the arguments when it goes to call print, so it doesn't need to make up a variable.  If you change the `let` to a `var` then code will actually be generated for that line, and the line will get its own line table entry.

If you know how to read assembly code, you can look at the mixed disassembly to see this in action.

In lldb:

```
(lldb) dis -m -f
```

will give you mixed disassembly of the current frame.

Comment: Thank you Jim.That really helps .can I assume that swiftc is also doing some other tricks as I experienced some other weird things like it wont stop on first line in the func block , instead it breaks on func declare line ? where can I find what does swiftc do ? Thanks

Comment: That seems likely.  There isn't any single place where the optimizer's behavior at -Onone is described, and the "optimizer" isn't one entity anyway, it's a bunch of separate passes each trying to do its own job.  You can see the "line table" that was present in the debug information with the lldb command `image dump line-table MySource.swift` but that will just tell you what information the debugger has, not why the swift compiler decided to frame it that way.